# Issue with Secondary monitor attached to macbook pro/ air

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I have following mac laptops
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) running high Sierra
MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2012) running Catalina

I use Asus 24' monitor as external display with these laptops. Recently i've noticed that both laptops stopped working with the monitor. External display is not detected under settings. When HDMI is plugged, and monitor is switched ON, laptop screen blinks (goes black) and then comes back to normal and nothing shows on external screen.
Since both laptop stopped at same time, my though problem is with external display. To verify i connected a video streaming device to the same HDMI port using the same HDMI cable and it worked.

I'm a bit confused why both mac stopped working with external display when a video streaming device still works on the same HDMI port with same HDMI cable.

I also tested both mac's with my TV HDMI port and they were able to use TV as external display without issues.

Is there something that i can debug or check?

Comment: Did you update the OS before it happened?

Comment: There were some updates recently. I can't say for sure. Assuming there was OS update, what do you think has happened ?